# How to label encode this in python?

Tags: data-analysis, label-encoding

How to label encode this in python?

```
array(['Video/Internet/Voice', 'Video/Internet', 'Internet Only',
       'Internet/Voice', nan, 'Video Only', 'Homesecurity Only',
       'Video/Internet/Voice/Homesecurity', 'Internet/Homesecurity',
       'Video/Internet/Homesecurity', 'Video/Voice',
       'Internet/Voice/Homesecurity', 'Voice Only', 'Video/Homesecurity',
       'Video/Voice/Homesecurity'], dtype=object)
```